# Predicting a Sine Wave Using ML in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am currently attempting to train a neural network that predicts a 1kHz sine wave.
While the model itself has an accuracy score of 0.89, it does not accurately predict my test data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

#Generate 1kHz sine wave

pi = np.pi

X = np.arange(0,2*pi,0.05)
y = np.sin(1000*X)

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=30)
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    
    
plt.plot(X_train, y_train)
plt.plot(X_test, y_test)
```

```
#Training using train samples

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train.reshape(-1,1))
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test.reshape(-1,1))


regr = MLPRegressor(random_state=1, max_iter=1000,hidden_layer_sizes=(32, 32)).fit(X_train, y_train)

regr.fit(X_train, y_train)


plt.plot(X_train, regr.predict(X_train), color = 'red')
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train)
regr.score(X_train, y_train)
```

[Result of training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCJeW.png)

```
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_test, regr.predict(X_test))
```

[Result of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sfNS.png)

As you can see, the test data is far less periodic than the ML model. Why is this the case?

Comment: You cannot use fit_transform on the test set as well. You can fit-transform to the training set, and only transform the test set. 

The reason why we separate train and test sets is, to predict on unseen data. If you fit and transform to the test data as well, the model considers test data as "seen" data already.

Comment: @ElvinAghammadzada Thanks, I didn't think of that. The model is more linear now, is there a reason for this? Perhaps I should just keep tuning the parameters here? https://i.imgur.com/n4TLgna.png

Comment: Your model probably does not generalize well.

Comment: I would try a RNN or related models like LSTM (or even a bi-directional LSTM) as they are optimized for data sequences.See e.g. https://www.kaggle.com/code/carlmcbrideellis/lstm-time-series-prediction-sine-wave-example/notebook